# I'm getting an unusual error when I'm trying to start my react app. It says that CleanWebpackPlugin is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, webpack

So, I have made a react app before with the same kind of configuration for webpack but this is the first time I am seeing this. The clean webpack plugin is showing that the class doesn't has a constructor even when it does.

I tried to see if there were any import problems or something like that but everything checks out.

```
const path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/index.js',
    style: './src/style.less'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
          test: /\.less$/,
          use: [{
              loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
              loader: 'css-loader'
          },
          {
              loader: 'less-loader'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html'
    }),
  ],
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

Here's the error that I get on my terminal

new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    ^

TypeError: CleanWebpackPlugin is not a constructor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your version.

the latest version of clean-webpack-plugin is **3.0.0** and the usage is

```
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
```

the previous version of clean-webpack-plugin is **2.0.2** and the usage is

```
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
```